# PushSharp - multiple invalid tokens don't invoke response delegates

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

I have an application that sends push notifications to ios devices using PushSharp.
It is a Windows Service. I try to test it for large scale with large lists of invalid deviceTokens(I don't have many valid tokens).

The problem is that the events of PushBroker are not triggered for most of the tokens.
Some tokens(very few) cause the method OnNotificationFailed to be fired (with a the message 'Invalid token' of course).

It might be a known behavior of apns on this scenario, for which PushSharp does not behave like I would expect it to. Im counting on these responses in my logic.

Is it reasonable to perform such a test ?

Should I expect such behavior ? What does it mean if PushBroker does not fire its events ?

thanks for any suggestion or comment you have.

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't looked into the PushSharp code, I implemented a server that communicates with APNS server, so I can give you some possible reasons for this behavior.

When Apple's APNS server encounters an invalid device token (or any other type of invalid data, such as too long payload), it writes an error response to the socket and closes the connection.

Now, if you try to send 10 notifications and only after the 10th message you get an error response (via `OnNotificationFailed` in your case) that says the 5th message failed, this means that Apple never processed message 6 to 10 (so if you expected `OnNotificationFailed` to be triggered for some of them, that's the reason why it didn't happen). These messages must be resent. I don't know if PushSharp handles this resending automatically or if you have to do it yourself.

In addition to this complication, in some cases (at least when I experimented with invalid tokens) you (or PushSharp in your case) might fail to read the error response from Apple, in which case you'll only notice that something wrong happened when the connection gets closed (i.e. you'll get a failure when trying to send a message).
In that case you have to open a new socket, but you have no idea which message caused the failure and which messages should be resent.

I suggest that you only use valid device tokens, and do your best to keep your DB free of invalid tokens, since it can be tricky to handle the error responses and connection closings caused by such tokens.

Comment: Thanks. So how can I test my service with multiple tokens ?

Comment: I understand that I cannot really test the service with invalid tokens, but I want to test the service for sending a large number of push notifications.

Will I get responses for all requests if I send 10,000 notifications for the same valid deviceToken ?

I tried to perform a similar test with GCM with a valid registration id - 10,000 requests to the same registration id. I haven't got responses to all requests.

How can I test this service for large number of tokens without having many unique tokens ?

Comment: @gilp Apple doesn't return a response when there is no error, so you won't get any response if you use valid tokens. The only way to test it for a large number of notifications without a large number of valid tokens is to write a process that simulates the APNS server (i.e. accepting incoming TLS connections and then parsing the incoming data according to the binary format of APNS). That's not easy to do. Another option is to test the entire process of sending multiple notifications except of the actual sending. That might require changes in the PushSharp source code.